# Variable length endpoints in jax-rs/microprofile client with Quarkus

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I'm facing the following issue and have been able to find a proper fix.

As a use case example, let's imagine a Rest client that fetches a json object from a server, where the request is the path to the object. This api does not accept query parameters nor bodies, and no catalogue is available.

say that I have the following RestClient:

```
@Path("/json")
@RegisterRestClient(configKey="json-api")
public interface JsonService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{MyVariableLengthEndpoint}")
    Response getJson(@PathParam("MyVariableLengthEndpoint") ????? endpoint);
}
```

Examples of requests could be :

- `/json/employees/Dwight/jobs/assistantRegionalManager/salary`
- `/json/games/theLastOfUs/rating`

Passing a string with / characters gets encoded with %. To bypass this, I've tried:

- Using the @Encoded annotation
- Adding a regex in the pathParameter `{MyVariableLengthEndpoint: .*}`
- Passing a `List<PathSegment>`

None of those worked.

Is there a proper way to do this ?

Comment: I have never used it, but `@ClientURI` may be the solution (https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.8.1.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#ClientURI).
Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You should use Regex in your @Path definition, something like this:

```
@GET
@Path(“/{varPath : .+}”)
Response getJson(@PathParam(“varPath”) String endpoint);
```

This will match anything that comes after /json.

For more info search: “JAXRS path Regex”, on Google.